# Type Checker For Generic Collection

Tags: rascal

I am trying to implement a TypeChecker for a Generic Collection as part of my DSL using Rascal’s TypePal library. I have gone through the examples that is included in the TypePal library am yet to see an example that illustrates this. Are there any such examples or can someone please help with it.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more research and after hours of hard work I am glad to say I finally implemented  Typing for Generics. I will gladly share my implementation here. However because of space constrain I will just post snippets of my implementation.

```
syntax Expr 
  = Id name
    | bracket \bracket: "(" Expr e")" 
    | literal : Literal literal
    | \set    : "{" {Expr ","}* el "}" 
    | \list   : "[" {Expr ","}* el "]"
    | \tuple  : "\<" {Expr ","}+ el "\>" 
    | \map    :  "{" {Mapping ","}* entries "}"
;

syntax Type
     = boolean: "Bool" 
     | string: "Str" 
     | integer: "Int"
     | float: "Float"
     | \set: "Set""[" Type t "]"
     | \map: "Map" "[" Type k "," Type v "]"
     | \list: "List""[" Type t "]"
     | dateTime: "Datetime"
;

void collect(current:(Expr)`{ <{Mapping ","}* entries> }`, Collector c) {
    mappings = [<k, v> | (Mapping) `<Expr k> -\> <Expr v>` <- entries];
    if (<k, v>  <- mappings){
        collect(entries, c);
        c.calculate("map type", current, [m | Mapping m <- entries], AType (Solver s) {
           for (<key, val> <- mappings) {
                s.requireEqual(k, key, error(key, "Expected same type in the list, found %t and %t", k, key));
                s.requireEqual(v, val, error(val, "Expected same type in the list, found %t and %t", v, val));
            }
           return mapType(s.getType(k), s.getType(v));
        });
    }
}


void collect(current: (Mapping) `<Expr k> -\> <Expr v>`, Collector c){
    c.calculate("mapping type", current, [k, v],
        AType(Solver s){ return mapType(s.getType(k), s.getType(v)); });
    collect(k, v, c);
}


void collect(current:(Expr)`[<{Expr ","} *entries>]`, Collector c) {
    if (e <- entries) {
        collect(entries, c);
        c.calculate("list type", current, [et | et <- entries], AType (Solver s) {
            for (et <- entries) {
                s.requireEqual(e, et, error(et, "Expected same type in the list, found %t and %t", e, et));
            }
           return listType(s.getType(e));
        });
    }
}
```